# iterate through several bootstrap sliders and get range values within an each function

Tags: bootstrap-slider

I have a page with several [bootstrap-sliders](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider). Here's a representative example:

```
<label>My Label 1</label>
<input id="mySlider1" data-slider-id='mySlider1' type="text"/>      

<label>My Label 2</label>
<input id="mySlider2" data-slider-id='mySlider2' type="text"/>
```

Here's the javascript definition for the sliders:

```
$("#mySlider1").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 5000,
    value: [0, 5000]
});

$("#mySlider2").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 5000,
    value: [0, 5000]
});
```

At some point I want to iterate through all the sliders and get their range values from within the 'each' loop:

```
$('.slider').each(function(){
    var key = $(this).attr("id");
    var value = $(this).val();  /* <- this is the problem line */
    console.log("key = " + key + ", value = " + value);
});
```

The console prints out:

```
key = mySlider1, value = 
key = mySlider2, value =
```

I would like to see 'value' as a 2-element array for the range [0,5000].

Comment: Have you tried doing x.bootstrapSlider('getValue')?

Comment: when I do x.bootstrapSlider('getValue') I get an error "cannot call methods on bootstrapSlider prior to initialization". I am instantiating with $("#mySlider1").slider({ stuff }). using this library https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

Comment: I would recommend making a working jsfiddle and then editing your post with your problem.

Comment: Here's a fiddle for the code above https://jsfiddle.net/mbL5j6qw/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a3wdzyck/ you need to add the class on the input object as that is where jQuery stores the slider instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are attempting to iterate over `.slider`, which is a class reserved for `bootstrap-slider`'s way of making a slider. You should add a slider to your `input` elements instead, such as in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a3wdzyck/